# Debug Windows Form targeted for ARM64 on x64 Windows Computer

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, debugging, 64-bit, arm64

I have created a Windows Forms application for my Raspberry Pi. Since the Raspberry has a ARM64 processor I have changed the target platform in Visual Studio 2022 to ARM64.

Now I obviously can't debug or release the application on the x64 device.

Is there a way to debug it?

Comment: Set the Debug Target to AnyCPU? The Release Target to what you have now.

Comment: You can't run a Winforms app on a Linux machine.  If you got a Windows install for that raspberry then use the remote debugger.

Comment: i have windows 10 running on the rpi

Comment: remote debugger? haven't heard of that what is it?

Comment: @Jimi but that way i still won't be able to release or debug it for the ARM64 chip

Comment: [Debugging on Arm64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-arm64) ->  [Remote Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2022). Get the Remote Tools from the [Download page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#remote-tools-for-visual-studio-2019) (`Tools for Visual Studio -> Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2022`)

Comment: well the debugging tool always gave me an error but I just changed the target platform to x86 and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the target to x86 and it worked!